# Firestore - how to get a document by id in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Title says it all, when I try to get a document by id from Firestore using code:

```
firestore
  .collection("my_collection")
  .get("foo")
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      console.log(doc.id, data);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents", err);
  });
```

It throws me this error:

`FirebaseError: FirebaseError: Function Query.get() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: "foo"`

So I supplied an object with an id: `{id: "foo"}`
which gave me another error:

`FirebaseError: FirebaseError: Unknown option 'id' passed to function Query.get(). Available options: source`

How can I get a document from collection by id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `get` method of firestore doesn't accept any argument.

You need to pass your id with the `doc` method, as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

```
firestore.collection('my_collection').doc('foo').get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const data = doc.data();
          console.log(doc.id, data);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the `id` and assign to a new `{key: value}`

See code below

[image]

```
const newProducts = [];
firestore()
  .collection("products")
  .where("category", "in", categories)
  .get()
  .then((docs) => {
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();

      // adding new property id with id from Firestore
      data.id = doc.id;

      newProducts.push(data);
    });
    setProducts(newProducts);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```